# MongoClient (from mongoDB Api) equivalent in LDAP

Tags: java, multithreading, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to provide a pool of connections to a LDAP db, I'm using unbound the problem is that in the structure that we are using, I need to create one instance of the connection and this instance must manage the resource usage limits as max connecctions, similar as creating an instance of [Mongoclient](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/)

> The MongoClient class is designed to be thread safe and shared among
>   threads. Typically you create only 1 instance for a given database
>   cluster and use it across your application.
>
> IMPORTANT When creating many MongoClient instances:
>
> All resource usage limits (max connections, etc) apply per MongoClient
>   instance To dispose of an instance, make sure you call
>   MongoClient.close() to clean up resources

The Unboundid sdk has the classes [LDAPConnectionPool](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/LDAPConnectionPool.html) class and the LDAPConnection. But do not have something that is similar to Mongoclient, for creating a single instance of an lDAPClient and this will be the one that take care of the usage limits. How can I implement this, this are examples for creating connection pools, but I think that this only create the connection pool but doesn't have an object as mongoclient

```
// Create a new LDAP connection pool with ten connections established and
   // authenticated to the same server:
   LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(address, port);
   BindResult bindResult = connection.bind(bindDN, password);
   LDAPConnectionPool connectionPool = new LDAPConnectionPool(connection, 10);
```

So my question is how can I build an LDAPclient similar to MOngoclient, or it is a library that I can use